# What is the difference between Task.Run(async).Wait() and sync method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I am implementing method for seeding data (and calling it in Startup.Configure() method) which looks like

```
if(!_context.Table.Any()) 
{
   _context.Table.Add();
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And I want to make it async using Task, so I changed my code to this

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
   if(! await _context.Table.AnyAsync()) 
   {
      await _context.Table.AddAsync();
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
});
```

But It didn't work. So I add `Wait()` to the `Task.Run()` and method started working.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
   if(! await _context.Table.AnyAsync()) 
   {
      await _context.Table.AddAsync();
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
}).Wait();
```

So, are there any differences between first and last parts of code?

As I know, `Wait()` method blocks the thread, so are these parts of code the same?

Comment: `Task.Run` = "I need this code to run somewhere else, *this* thread has got other work to do" - `.Wait` = "This thread cannot do anything useful until this other thing has finished". How do you think using them both together makes sense?

Comment: "*But it didn't work.*" what was the problem?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'd say it makes (some) sense in legacy code when (1) this thread has to orcestrate multiple tasks before it waits for all of them or (2) the called async method with poor implementation needs to be embedded in a sync context without deadlocking. So basically, don't write new code that sync-waits for no reason, but don't waste years just to avoid such code, when dealing with legacy.